# elantech touchpad mouse-up fails on win10

Tags: touchpad, windows-10-upgrade

Windows 10 upgrades seems to have caused a myriad of touchpad-problems for users of several different laptop brands including Acer, Lenovo, Asus and others. But I have not yet found anyone with the same problem as me. -Surely I cannot be the only one with this problem?

When I click (on buttons, links etc) with my touchpad, the mouse-down event is triggered, but not the mouse-up event. -Not until the next time I move the mouse!

I have tried installing the win8.1 driver for the touchpad, and that kind-of works, except then the scroll-direction gets inverted and that is almost as annoying. (also, the win10 driver updates it self back in sometimes...)

I have also tried to find the unbranded elantech-driver for win10 64bit, but all I found was the Asus Smart Gesture with the same driver that came with the windows upgrade...

Computer: Asus Zenbook UX51VZ

Touchpad HW-id: ACPI\VEN_ETD&DEV_0105

Comment: Have you reported this problem to ASUS?

Comment: Best solution I came up with is Windows 7 driver + [blocking driver updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930).

Comment: I've had several issues with computers I've upgraded to Windows 7, even a blown ethernet card. I've found that the best way to fix all issues with it is to refresh Windows 10 and check to make sure all drivers are up-to-date once the refresh is done. That fixed all the issues I had, but make sure to have a backup display and ethernet/wireless driver on hand in case they get deleted. The reason I say refresh is because, in the upgrade, there are too many corruptions made by the installer to properly fix. Best of luck.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I have reported it to ASUS, but I'm not holding my breath for a constructive response :P

Comment: @Dooley_labs When you say refresh you mean download win10 installer to do a clean install instead of an upgrade?

Comment: @Superole "Refresh is part of reset in Windows 10. Step 1: Open the Start menu, and then select Settings > Update & security > Recovery. Step 2: Under Reset this PC, select Get started. Step 3: Select Keep my files." -from [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/refresh-is-part-of-reset-in-windows-10#).

Comment: @Dooley_labs Great, that sounds like it is worth a try. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question was made, ASUS released Elantech drivers for Win10.

You can find the latest Elantech driver [here](https://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10/#other). However, I would suggest you to install the Smart Gesture driver which also includes the ELAN driver.

Comment: Hey Ivan, Your page is simply great! I visited it even before I posted this question :D And if I can just get this to work, I will accept this answer.